# Azure Data Factory linking GitHub repository for Source Control?

Tags: azure, github, azure-data-factory

Is there a way to create an ARM template resource so that a GitHub repository can be added into an Azure Data Factory for source control?

I was able to do it in the UI easily. Is this only something that can be done manually after the factory is spun up?

I am not talking about linking GitHub as a service in ADF, that is a different thing. I am looking to have the source control connection made for any published pipelines/datasets to be put into GitHub with their respective parameter files. Mainly looking to automate this for an initial ADF deployment so there is less clicking around done in the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the ARM template and parameter file to automate both factory creation and source control setup. See the image for reference.

[image]